# Calling a method on a constructor method

Tags: java, android, constructor

I saw this line of code while doing an Android tutorial, and it compiles:

```
Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
```

How can you call the getTime() method on a constructor. To my knowledge the constructor doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor doesn't return anything in itself, but it results in the creation of a new object, in this case `GregorianCalendar`. What's happening in the code above, is you are just using a member method after creation of this object following the construction.

If it helps, your code above would be equivalent to:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Your example just does it in one line instead of two.

Comment: Normally, whenever I've seen a method called on an object, it was either the object's reference variable or on a method that returned an object. Guess this is just another way of doing it. So the purpose of this is that you don't have any use for the calendar object after you've initialized the date object?

Comment: @khakis that's right, yes. Another way of looking at it is by adding extra brackets, which may make it clearer: Date date = (new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day)).getTime();

Comment: More accurately: the constructor does not return anything, but the keyword `new` does.